# Internship with reduced pay

Tags: salary, internship

I am a full time student and have been working part-time as a contractor for the past 7 months developing an app for a company. They have recently announced that they would like me to continue working for them, as an intern over the summer. I would be working double the hours I do currently and doing almost identical work, with no new experiences.

However my employer has announced that since I will be an intern, I will be paid 25% less than my current hourly rate, in order for it to "be fair for the other interns" who will also receive this lower rate.

This company and my employer have been very good to me, and have made it clear that they are impressed with my work, so I am somewhat confused as to why they are choosing to lower my pay. Naturally I feel rather annoyed at being paid less for the same work, and I am wondering whether I should agree to sign up for this reduced pay. I have been considering asking whether it would be possible to continue on my current contract with the same hours and the same pay, but I am terrified of upsetting my boss who has been so lovely, and I really do not want to lose this job!

TL;DR Should I continue working for a company who want to lower my salary?

Thank you!

Comment: *"... I will be paid 25% less than my current hourly rate, in order for it to 'be fair for the other interns'"* - That's pure horsehockey, right there.  You have to make your own decision, but I wouldn't stand for this.

Comment: I don't think anyone in their right mind should consider a largely illogical pay-cut (the reason literally makes no sense) in a high-demand industry like software development. Consider this: The interns who have no *company-specific* experience will be taking their sweet time doing intern stuff like learning to walk, and you'll be developing apps. I'm somewhat dramatizing the interns, but seriously.

Comment: I'm sure the other interns would understand "Genierock has been working for us part time for 7 months, and so gets paid a bit more."

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan The other interns technically shouldn't know what Genieirock is making to begin with, IMO.

Comment: @CMosychuk Agreed. I'm just saying that even if they knew I don't think they would consider it unfair.

Comment: I'm worried about coming across as greedy or rude, how would you recommend I let my boss know that I want to continue to be paid the same rate without sounding almost spoiled?

Comment: What country? In the USA, it's not legal for an intern to produce profitable work - everything you do should be training. See https://www.dol.gov/whd/regs/compliance/whdfs71.htm; on that basis, you cannot be an intern.

Comment: @Genieirock are you doing the same/similar work as the other interns? You can always try and say that you can't be compared to the other interns since the work is clearly different. Also you are not really getting less salary. You are getting 50% more which is still worth considering. If you can't make those hours as a contractor then why refuse yourself that by complaining about getting a to me good Job.

Comment: @Drewbenn: You may have a point there. You might gather, though, that I'm not a fan of internships in any way, shape or form. If you're good enough to do a job, you're good enough to get paid for it and to not have a demeaning title like 'intern' - especially if you're developing an app! Good app developers at the moment are impossible to find.

Comment: @RaoulMensink My work is indeed completely different to everyone else, I am the only app developer they have. However I do agree that the extra hours are nice and it is true that I will make more every month

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To follow through from the comments earlier, you state that you have to submit invoices to be paid.  So in fact you are a contractor working part time, paid on an hourly rate.

It's very normal to earn a higher rate *per hour* as a contractor, to compensate for the lack of stability and any benefits.  Now as an intern, you have a stable, fixed income each week for a set number of hours.  I don't know if you accrue leave or anything, but that too is factored into the overheads of the wage you are paid.

I don't think anything is wrong here, it's just changing from contract to employment.

Comment: In the abstract, sure, but if the OP is "developing an app" for the company then being paid at an intern rate (as well as being a contractor at 25% above an intern rate) is too low.  And being paid the same as new interns, who do not have any experience with the company, is also unfair.

Comment: @dan1111 he is a Student and as such he can't really Claim a professional pay. We can't speak about his experience other than the 7 months he has been working for his current "Boss". He still is getting more Money out of the deal in total. Also your calculation is wrong: his contractor rate is 33% higher ( contract hourly = 4/3 intern hourly = 33% more as a contractor which means he is getting 25% less of his current hourly)

Comment: Unless the reduction in financial compensation is offset by other compensation (paid vacation, insurance, retirement plane etc), the OP is getting ripped off. @RaoulMensink the OP's status as a student in no way justifies lower pay for the same work.

Comment: @RaoulMensink good catch on my calculation.  It's true that our knowledge of the OP's ability/work is limited.  But the question creates the impression that the OP is doing professional-level software development work, and if that is the case, they should be paid more than an intern.

Comment: @DLS3141 I agree, but also the stability and guaranteed hours are _one_ offset.  It's up to the OP to decide if it's sufficiently so, if there are no other benefits.

Comment: @DLS3141 that is a common Thing to do though as it merely states he has no experience in the field and that is a reason to pay someone less than someone who has or even has a education. Just my 2 Cents.

Comment: @RaoulMensink he has the experience he's gained as a contractor, and is currently contributing at a level above what the other, totally green student interns can accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Are you being mentored or otherwise receiving some sort of on the job education in this position?  If yes, then maybe it's ok to call you an intern.  If no, sounds like you are a regular employee.

In either case, it is not acceptable to lower your current pay - especially if they are happy enough with your work that they want you to stay.

I suggest you discuss with your boss and just say "if you like my work thus far, I think you should continue my pay as it stands.  Other 'interns' won't know what I make, so that should not be an issue."

Comment: Actually it sounds like the original student work was paid as a contractor.  As an intern (or an employee), you have more guaranteed hours, and so the rate of pay _per hour_ is normally lower to reflect this.

Comment: He said he was a part time employee. Generally, part-time employees make less per hour than full-time employees, but it's usually not 25%.

Comment: Still could be a part time contractor. Nowhere does the OP specifically state that they are an employee.

Comment: @mjulmer I haven't received any kind of mentoring or training from the company at any point while I have been working for them, and I agree that were I doing new work and gaining new experience during this internship the pay cut _might_ make sense, but it is just the same work as I have been doing for the past months.

Comment: @JaneS To be honest I'm not sure what the company consider me, I was interviewed and given the job based on this, and have met a number of employees in the company, as well as being invited to work socials, etc. However I don't have a company email address as I know some of the others do, and I currently have no set hours per se, only a hourly rate for as many hours as I work every week.

Comment: @Genieirock Do you have to supply an invoice to get paid?

Comment: @JaneS Yes, I do. However I have just found the original email I sent when I first applied for the job and I referred to it as "the part-time app developer position you are advertising", so I assume this is the role they advertised for, but I seem to be unable to find the original job listing.

Comment: @Genieirock In that case my original comment stands.  You were paid a higher hourly rate because you were a contractor.  They aren't diddling you, they have instead put you in a position where you now have a stable income for fixed hours, for all intents and purposes as an employee.

Comment: @Genieirock If you are currently working as an independent contractor you should mention this in your post. Right now it is not clear this is the case from reading it.